# How to log Trace in .NET Core library?

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-core, logging, trace

I know you can use dependency injection of ILogger in program or controller, so the log message could appear in console and other loggers. However, in a .net core library, I would like to use Trace.TraceError() and Trace.TraceInformation() etc., and even use TraceSource.

Is is possible to make what in Trace.TraceError(...) appear in .NET Core console and other loggers?

Comment: Did you read the documentation on [.Net Core logging and tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/logging-tracing)?

Comment: Surely I did, but apparently the doc is not covering everything it mentioned in details.

Comment: [TraceSource is specifically mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#tracesource-provider) as a provider.

Comment: Likely they replaced TraceSource with DiagnosticSource that is more powerfull.

Comment: Did you read the question? He's asking about Trace.Trace...() to appear in .NET Core logging, not the other way around. Here's how: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5255953/Use-Trace-and-TraceSource-in-NET-Core-Logging

Answer (score 1):

Just include an ILogger in the constructor of your libary.  Calls to Log methods on the logger will then get passed through to whatever LoggerProviders (Trace, Console etc) have been [added in your configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-providers).

```cs
public class MyLib
{
  private ILogger _logger;

  public MyLib(ILogger<MyLib> logger)
  {
    _logger = logger;
  }

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    _logger.LogInformation("Info")
    _logger.LogError("Error")
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem is `ILogger` isn't available from the very beginning (when your process starts).